# Lock a Cell Within a Range After Content Has Been Entered in Excel Through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that is acting as an inventory entry point for a hand scanner. When a code is scanned the scanner automatically hits return and selects the next cell down. I want the cells that have content entered into them to automatically be protected or lock while leaving the empty cells available for editing.

Unfortunately my current VBA code is locking the entire range whenever I enter anything anywhere within that range. Any ideas on what I could do to fix this? I have never worked in VBA before so I am very lost when it comes to this stuff. This code is basically through trial and error and Googling things.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = Range("A:A")

    If Not MyRange Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("Data In").Unprotect Password:="mypassword"
        MyRange.Locked = True
        Sheets("Data In").Protect Password:="mypassword"
    End If

End Sub
```

Again, very new to VBA so if I am missing something super obvious please let me know.

Thanks!!

Comment: I'd use `Worksheet_Change` here instead of `SelectionChange`.

Comment: I don't think that this statement `If Not MyRange Is Nothing` is checking for what you expect it to

Comment: Is Column A the only one with changes?

Comment: Yes, column A should be the only one being edited

Comment: As @Marcucciboy2 says, you probably want to be instead checking `If Not Intersect(MyRange, Target) Is Nothing` (i.e. "were the cells that I changed in Column A"), and work from there.  Also, instead of using `Unprotect` and `Protect`, read up on the `UserInterfaceOnly` argument of `Protect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your issue is actually that you're not **unlocking** the [rest of the empty range](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=1203). This will only lock the cells in column A which already have values.

Like BigBen, I would also suggest using `Worksheet_Change` instead of `Worksheet_SelectionChange`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    With Me
        ''unprotect for VBA only
        .Protect Password:="mypassword", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

        ''lock entire column
        .Range("A:A").Locked = True

        ''unlock empty cells in the usedrange
        On Error Resume Next  'xlCellTypeBlanks will error out when there are no blank cells in the UsedRange
        .Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = False

        ''unlock empty cells after the usedrange
        .Range(.Range("A" & UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1), .Range("A" & UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1).End(xlDown)).Locked = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: 2 comments:  First, if you use `With Me`, then you can use the code in any Worksheet, and it will automatically apply the code to itself instead of `Sheets("Data In")`.  Second, instead of using `.Unprotect Password:="mypassword"` and `.Protect Password:=mypassword`, just replace `.Unprotect Password:="mypassword"` with `.Protect Password:="mypassword", UserInterfaceOnly:=True` - this will allow VBA to edit the sheet, but not the user!  (Technically, this only needs to be called once, but the setting is "dropped" when you close and reopen the workbook)

Comment: @Chronocidal thanks for the tips! I rarely use `.Protect` and didn't read the documentation before my post as you could probably tell. I also can't really tell if OP's machine is only adding data in column A so I intentionally omitted the `.Intersect` check

Comment: Hmm...  Would it be better to Lock all the cells, and then Unlock `UsedRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`?  (After checking if it `Is Nothing` first!)

Comment: That final version works perfectly! Thank you all so much!

Comment: @Chronocidal ugly as the original, but seems to do the job :/